# How to change badge color depending date_diff results?

Tags: php, date, if-statement, colors, diff

i have a table with three dates, and i use date_diff to find some results, and its working.
This results are displayed inside a bootstrap badge, but im trying that depending the result the badge change color.

```
<?php
$date1 = date_create($lines3x['date_open']);
$date2 = date_create($lines3x['date_close']);
$date3 = date_create($lines3x['date_finish']);
//difference between two dates
$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
$diff2 = date_diff($date2,$date3);
?>

 <td><span class="badge badge-info"><? echo $diff2->format("%a");?></span></td>
```

For example if the $diff2 result between 10 and 20 the badge should be like this:

```
<span class="badge badge-warning">`
```

ìf bigger than 20 the badge should be:

```
<span class="badge badge-danger">`
```

Any ideas to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try JQuery for that..

give an id to span and go for this..
put on the condition which you want.
if it's true then go for this between script tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(#id).addClass("class name");
}
);
</script>
```

and there You go ..
don't forget to load jquery .js file before the code otherwise it ll throwan error.
Thank You.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

here it is..
and make sure you load cdn of jquery before your code otherwise it ll return console error that $ is not defined...

```
<?php
 $date1 = date_create($lines3x['date_open']);
 $date2 = date_create($lines3x['date_close']);
 $date3 = date_create($lines3x['date_finish']);
    //difference between two dates
 $diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
 $diff2 = date_diff($date2,$date3);
 if($diff2 >10 && $diff2<20)
 {
    ?>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $(.diff).addClass('badge-warning');
     });
 </script>
 <?php
}elseif($diff2>20)
{
     ?>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $(.diff).addClass('badge-danger');
     });
 </script>
 <?php
}else{
     ?>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $(.diff).addClass('badge-info');
     });
 </script>
 <?php
}
?>

    <td><span class="diff badge"><? echo $diff2->format("%a");?></span></td>
```

Comment: i inserted the jquery cdn on the head section and paste your code, but it doesnt work. The value appears but no badge is displayed.

Comment: Habe u tried inspect element to check weather the class is set or not

Comment: Please let me know... It ll be helpful to identify the error and also check console errors as well and give it to me .